# Java, Glassfish JPA: NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo (JDK6/7 only)

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish

I'm fairly new to Java EE6 and Glassfish3. I was trying to build my own application when I got this error.

> NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo

Assuming it was an ignorance issue I started following this tutorial: 
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-gettingstarted.html#Exercise_1

I still got the same issue. The exact trace is:

> An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception. Consult the
>   following stack trace for details. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:350)
>     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:793)
>     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:722)
>     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1700(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:97)
>     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1029)
>     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1163)
>     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1106)
>     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
>     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:417)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:331)  at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:322)  at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:76)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.Javac13.execute(Javac13.java:56)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1134)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:912)   at
>   org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant.JavacTask.execute(JavacTask.java:144)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor40.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor40.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor40.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)  at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)    at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:284)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:539)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)     ... 49 more
>   /home/alan/Projects/SimpleEE6App/SimpleEE6App/nbproject/build-impl.xml:550:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /home/alan/Projects/SimpleEE6App/SimpleEE6App/nbproject/build-impl.xml:263:
>   Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details. BUILD
>   FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

The `javax.persistence.spi` jar with the `PersistenceUnitInfo.class` does exist on the Glassfish server 3, I can see it through Netbeans. Explicitly adding any combination of JPA libraries (EclipseLink, Persistence, etc.) does nothing to stop the error.
So I'm totally stuck at this point as to why the build process cannot find the appropriate class.

Any ideas?

Update: I figured out what was causing it but am not sure why? In Netbeans->Project properties->Libraries->Processor(tab) it listed eclipselink (JPA2.0) and EclipseLink-ModelGen(JPA 2.0). Once I removed those it worked. Netbeans adds them automatically when you create an entity. I'm running Netbeans 7.0.1. 
Thanks for everybody's help.

Comment: When does this error occur? When you create a fresh project without any Persistence code, will it build?

Comment: yes it will build. it is only after adding an entity class that it fails.

Answer (score 3):

The root cause can only be that the JAR is not on the classpath available to the process that is throwing the exception at runtime. When you say that the JAR "does exist", can you verify its presence on the classpath? It is not enough for it just to be in a folder under the server install.

If you have a WEB-INF directory in a web project you could try copying the JAR to the WEB-INF/lib directory because JARs in that directory are guaranteed by the servlet spec to be added to the classpath as part of an application install.

Comment: the file: javax.persistence.jar exists in the ~/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/ folder. The GLASSFISH_HOME env is set to "~/glassfish3/"
When I added the file to /WEB-INF/lib/ it still did the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because it cannot find the specified class `javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo`

To get this class, you need javax.persistence.jar file in your class path. You can [download  it from here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/STUVWXYZ/Downloadjavaxpersistencejar.htm)